# How to tranlate "read more" and other buttons on wordpress using qTranslate?

Tags: wordpress, qtranslate

I am having issue with translating entire wordpress blog to Azerbaijani language. I am using qTranslate plugin for this. It translates all the content but doesn't translate hard coded labels of buttons like 'Read More' and Share on Links. Here is the website: http://alpha1.dentalblog.az/home/ 
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself have used qTranslate to add multi laungauge support on my website and have not implented button translation either
Pretty sure you can use tags within the buttons to support multiple laungauges
For instance:

```
[:en]English[:de]Deutsch
```

Comment: In my theme Read more is called by function as follows: <?php echo theme_locals("read_more"); ?></a>, I cannot simply implement that shortcode, I can use it in header titles and content but not in buttons. Is there any solution for this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After so many attempts and digging through endless files of John-Doe-Blog theme I found a solution. I changed

```
<?php echo theme_locals("read_more") to 
echo _e("<!--:az-->Some text in Azerbaijani<!--:--><!--:ru-->Some text in Russian<!--:-->")
```

The same applies for all the other small areas which needs the same type of translation.
Hope it helps.